# @ManyToMany relation between more than two table in jpa hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, many-to-many

There are Three Tables: Customer, Product, and Warehouse. as you see there is Many-To-Many relation between warehouse-product and customer-product.

how should I join these tables?
I can handle @ManyToMany relation between two tables but here I need one join table for these.

should I create another entity, like CPW, and change the relations to "OneToMany" for Customer-CPW and "ManytoOne" for CPW-Customer and so on.
In this case, how can I initialize the tables? 
when you have only two tables you can create a Set<> of other entity and add some values but here I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you actually mean by _but here I need one join table for these_? Is it that you need to know for all `Products` of some `Customer` that from which `Warehouse` some  `Product` is from, for example? And if user can have more than one items of some `Product` and can those be from more than one `Warehouse`?

Comment: There is an online shop which user login and select products. the user does not care about warehouse so do I, for the user we don't have to show warehouse details beside product details. but when admin login, product, and warehouse relation should be shown in details. actually, I need customer-product and product-warehouse table. but I face an error when I add two @ManyToMany annotations in product entity.